# Authentication failed on secondary mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4

I have primary mongodb v3.4.10 on ubuntu (bare metal) with these users:

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.root",
    "user" : "root",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

Secondray is docker image with this config (I start secondary-newnode with initial sync and it become secondary):

```
    services:
      mongodb:
        image: mongo:3.4.15-jessie
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - /opt/mongodb/data:/data/db
          - /opt/mongodb/replication.key:/data/db/ssl/replication.key
        network_mode: "host"
        command: --storageEngine=wiredTiger --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB=12 --journal --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost,192.168.50.3 --auth --keyFile /data/db/ssl/replication.key
```

Now, when i want connect to secondary, with mongo shell authenticataion failed with

```
    Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18, codeName: "AuthenticationFailed" }
    0
```

forced to new node become PRIMARY not work.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. This is the mongo client issue. I added mongodb repository and install mongo shell

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list

# apt-get update; apt-get install mongodb-org-shell
```